# Autocomplete error json

Tags: javascript, spring

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:fragment="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#buscar_producto").autocomplete({
            source : function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "/factura/cargar-productos/" + request.term,
                    dataType : "json",
                    data : {
                        term : request.term
                    },
                    success : function(data) {
                        response($.map(data, function(item) {
                            return {
                                value : item.id,
                                label : item.nombre,
                                precio : item.precio,
                            };
                        }));
                    },
                });
            },
            select : function(event, ui) {


                var linea = $("#plantillaItemsFactura").html();

                linea = linea.replace(/{ID}/g, ui.item.value);
                linea = linea.replace(/{NOMBRE}/g, ui.item.label);
                linea = linea.replace(/{PRECIO}/g, ui.item.precio);

                $("#cargarItemProductos tbody").append(linea);

                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Este es mi controlador

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/cargar-productos/{term}", produces = { "application/json" })
public @ResponseBody List<Producto> cargarProductos(@PathVariable String term) {
    return proveedorService.findByNombre(term);
}
```

Este es el json que me captura

```
[
   {
      "id":3,
      "nombre":"samsung A21",
      "descripcion":"2do registro ",
      "cantidad":25,
      "precio":800.0,
      "imagen":"a21.jpg",
      "usuario":{
         "id":1,
         "nombre":"admin",
         "apellido":"admin",
         "username":"admin",
         "email":"admin@gmail.com",
         "provincia":null,
         "distrito":null,
         "direccion":null,
         "telefono":null,
         "tipo":"ADMIN",
         "password":"admin",
         "departamento":"LIMA",
         "productos":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "nombre":"iphone 13 pro max ",
               "descripcion":"126gb",
               "cantidad":20,
               "precio":5999.0,
               "imagen":"iphone_13_pro_alpine_green.55e3e7ff.png",
               "usuario":{
                  "id":1,
                  "nombre":"admin",
                  "apellido":"admin",
                  "username":"admin",
                  "email":"admin@gmail.com",
                  "provincia":null,
                  "distrito":null,
                  "direccion":null,
                  "telefono":null,
                  "tipo":"ADMIN"
               }
            ]
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código como texto en lugar de usar screenshots. Haz el recorrido (que está en el footer) para que conozcas las reglas de la comunidad.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español! Antes que todo te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por el [tour] y aprovecha y mira como [ask] correctamente. El código debede estar en formato texto y no con imágenes. Pulsa [edit] y cambia esto último.

Comment: Podrías dar una explicación de que es lo que quieres o que tendría que pasar o lo que necesitas.....